# What is the effective difference between using "echo $image;" and "echo $image->getImageBlob();"

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

In [examples at php.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php), I see the following:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$image = new Imagick('image.jpg');
// ...do stuff...
echo $image;
?>
```

However, I came across [samples](https://github.com/Danack/Imagick-demos/blob/master/src/ImagickDemo/Imagick/functions.php) that use:

```
echo $image->getImageBlob();
```

So I was wondering what the advantage/disadvantage of using the [getImageBlob() method](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageblob.php) is, compared to just an echo statement with the object itself. Both worked fine in the cases in which I tried them.

Comment: according to the docs there doesn't seem to be a difference, except __toString() doesn't throw errors...

Comment: Incidentally, while linking to the manual, I was rather puzzled by the subdomains at the PHP site. `http://php.net/[path]` and 
 `http://www.php.net/[path]` both work without one redirecting to the other (already a bit odd), `https://php.net/[path]` redirects to `https://secure.php.net/[path]` (which is quite strange for a website in this decade), and (oddest of all) `https://www.php.net/[path]` fails to respond at all.

Comment: @Jeff Hrm... I wonder why they didn't have __toString likewise throw errors, instead of just returning an empty string on failure. Perhaps getImageBlob() (along with getImage*s*Blob() ) was added to Imagick later, and they didn't want to wreck things for existing code.

Comment: `__toString()` must return a string, and mustn't throw errors. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Comment: @Sammitch Ah, thanks. My mistake.